# Receiving and creating sub comments LinkedIn company page

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to receive and create sub comments (on behalf of my company page) on LinkedIn using the REST API. I've created an example post:

[Example post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gavDJ.png)

When calling https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/900153/updates/?start=0&count=100, I receive the post itself ("Level 1 post") and my comment ("Level 2, comment"). The LinkedIn website allows me to create a sub comment under "Level 2, comment", which I did.

Now I don't seem to be able to receive this "Level 3, sub comment". I've tried using /v1/companies/900153/updates/key=UPDATE-c900153-6282480798125948928/update-comments/?format=json, but this will only return my level 2 comment. At the same time, I can't find a way to create a sub comment using the REST API, like I did on the website itself.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I am also finding way to get sub comments of a comment of LinkedIn post. Please let me know if you find any API.